# Reordering commands in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile

```
.PHONY: target1
target1: target2
  command1
```

My job is to run command1 before target2. For that, I have split command1 into command1 and command2 and rewritten the Makefile as follows:

```
.PHONY: target1
target1:
    command1
target1: target2
    command2
```

But when I run this Makefile, it is only executing target2 and command2. command1 is not run.

Comment: You _run_ or _execute_ commands in recipes but you _build_ targets. So, when you write that you want to _run command1 before target2_ what do you mean? If you mean that `command1` is the first step to build `target2`, then put it as first line of `target2` recipe. If you mean that `target2` cannot be built before `command1` has been run, then a target (`target3`) is missing in your problem statement. `target2` shall have `target3` as prerequisite and the recipe of `target3` shall be `command1`.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer relies on the order in which the prerequisites are listed. This does not work with parallel make. So, if you really need to run `command1` before building `target2` you should consider declaring the real dependencies, and not try to use make as another bizarre scripting language.

Comment: If you really wrote the makefile like this, then make would give you a warning message saying you had redefined `target1`.  That's why `command1` is not run: you can't create two different recipes for the same target.  You should definitely pay attention to any warnings make generates, and if not you should at least include them in any questions you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to rename the first `target1` to something else and call it before the `target2` rule. Something like:

```
.PHONY: target1 target1_cmd
target1_cmd:
    command1
target1: target1_cmd target2
    command2
```

This will run `command1`, whatever is in `target2` and then run the `command2`.

I'm not sure I get everything that you are trying to do but let me know if you need more details and explanation.

Comment: `target1_cmd` should be marked as `.PHONY` too.

Comment: With parallel make this does not guarantee that `command1` runs before `target2` is built. To guarantee this `target2` shall also depend on `target1_cmd`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet no mention of parallel make here, but yeah you are right

Comment: It is ok if command1 and target2 are parallel. The problem with the earlier implementation is that target2 happens first and then command1.

Answer (score 1):

If `command1` is the first step to build `target2`, simply add it in its recipe:

```
target1: target2
    command2

target2:
    command1
    <rest of target2 recipe>
```

If you want to execute `command1` before building `target2`, what's missing in your problem statement is a third target which recipe is `command1`. If `command1` creates a file `target3` then it is easy:

```
target1: target2
    command2

target2: target3
    <target2 recipe>

target3:
    command1
```

If `command1` does not create any file, you can use an empty marker file as an indicator that `command1` has been executed:

```
target1: target2
    command2

target2: target3
    <target2 recipe>

target3:
    command1
    touch "$@"
```

Finally, if `target1` and `target2` shall be built each time you invoke make, just declare all these as phony:

```
.PHONY: target1 target2 target3

target1: target2
    command2

target2: target3
    <target2 recipe>

target3:
    command1
```